# Setting a dateformat in struts2 tag using application aware

Tags: struts2

The requirement is that the admin will select the date format from the list say
("dd-MM-yyyy","d MMM  yyyy") based on the this selection all the date to be displayed should be as per the selection.

as this setting should apply throught out the application i tried saving it in a application scope using application aware . i was able to save but the problem was when trying to implement the changes

means

```
GlobelSetting global = new GlobelSetting();
global.setFormatDate("dd-MM-yyyy");
applicationMap.put("dateFormat", global.getFormatDate());
```

now trying to set the date format in date tag

```
<td align="left"> 
 <s:date name="employee.dateCreated" format="#application.dateFormat"/></td>
```

but i get a error while displaying the error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'p'
```

Comment: have you tried printing the `application.dateFormat` to see how it is coming?

Comment: ok will try printing it lets see how it prints

Comment: i printed it using struts property tag it showed dd-MM-yyyy  the format i set no idea where the problem lies now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "format" attribute needs to have evaluation forced:

```
<s:date name="employee.dateCreated" format="%{#application.dateFormat}" />
```

Comment: Dave Newton Buddy to good thanks a lot i need to perfect ognl syntax thanks a lot again :) no wonders why u have 51.6k reputation